# NoErrorObjectAvailable Script error in Analytics studio

Tags: einstein-analytics, analytics

I am trying to delete a dataset stored in my private app. It keeps giving me the below error:-

> This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it.
> [NoErrorObjectAvailable] Script error.

[image]

I want to know what causes it or any other way to delete the dataset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it now. I have created a recipe from this dataset and it was preventing the deletion. As soon as i deleted the recipe, it worked.
[image]

The error message earlier was not much helpful.